# Ajax working only in IE

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

Can someone tell me which are the main differences, or aspects that I should look for, if the AJAX I'm using works perfectly on IE but does not work at all on Google Chrome or Firefox?

Are there some things that IE accept but the others dont? Or is there any code that I should add in order to works for all the browsers?

I dont know if this affect something, but I'm working with PYTHON!

Here is the code that all the Ajax functions use as base:

```
var xmlhttp;
var request = true;

function GetXmlHttpObject() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (trymicrosoft) {
        try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml12.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (othermicrosoft) {
            try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
            return false; //or null
            }
        }
    }
    if (!request) 
    alert ("Error initializing XMLHTTPRequest!");
    return request;
}
```

After doing this, I use a regular Javascript function which includes something like this:

```
var url = 'evaluacionDesempenoBD.py?cadena=' + cadena + '&comentario=' + comentario + '&idEvaluacion=' + idEvaluacion + '&seccion=' + seccion;

xmlhttp = GetXmlHttpObject();
if (!xmlhttp) {
   alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
   return;
}
var xml = xmlhttp;
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);'''
```

I hope i made myself clear
Thanks a lot!

Comment: What errors are you getting? What code are you using?

Comment: We'd need to see the code, but it sounds like you're only creating an `ActiveX` object, and not a `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: @Quentin I have a very large code. The AJAX function simply go to another script which inserts something on a DataBase.

Comment: check jquery ajax. it's faster codding and you get rid of "not working on this browser"

Comment: @Quentin I already put some code. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has [an awesome article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) on XMLHttpRequest with some sample code that should help you get your AJAX thingie work across all browsers.

Perhaps you might be facing a problem due to browser differences with regards to the internals of the XMLHttpRequest object, particularly how you handle readystate changes. Quirksmode has [a document](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html) on this.

Answer (score 3):

You probably use the ActiveX AJAX object and not the native implementation supported by all browsers.

Use `new XMLHttpRequest()` to create an AJAX object on browsers with native implementation.